# Horizontally Overflowing element requires overflow-y to be visible, why?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display some overflow elements next to a dialog.
The dialog is a normal relative positioned div (via Vuetify for vuejs)
The overflow elements are supposed to be displayed next to the dialog.

I've replicated the issue with vanilla html + css

Running this, we can see that the inner most div is clipped by the parent div.
However, setting `overflow-y: visible` makes the overflow element appear correctly.

My question is basically, why does overflow-y matter here when the overflow is on the x axis?

```html
<div>
  <div style="width:50%;position:relative;left:25%;background-color:red;height:50%;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:visible;">
    aaa
    <div style="position:absolute;top:20px;left:90%;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:green">
      bbb
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#overflow-properties):

> Computed value: as specified, except with visible/clip computing to auto/hidden (respectively) if one of overflow-x or overflow-y is neither visible nor clip

So if you set one of the overflow to `auto` the other one will also get computed to `auto`. In your case `overflow-x` will be `auto` and no more `visible`.

In other words, you cannot have a combination of `visible` and `auto`. If you use both, then the result will be `auto` for the one using `visible`

[image]